# Vertically align icon in table cell which also includes text without making the column significantly wider

Tags: html, css, alignment

I have the below table which is as small of an example as I can make it on short notice. The problem I have is in the 4th column, I have an icon, some text and then another icon. Here's what I'm looking for:

- I want the first icons and the text to align left, as they are now.
- I want the second icons to always appear vertically aligned with each other across rows.
- I want the second icons to always be near the end of the longest line of text in that row, without overlapping that text if the text becomes too long.
- This should work, even if the number in the text is 6 or 7 digits long and the window is so narrow that the current implementation pushes the second icon onto the second row because of the padding.
  As an example, the below image is the current implementation when the window is narrowed down. I'd rather not the icon gets wrapped onto the next line unless there's no other option.

[image]

I've tried several options:

- the current implementation;
- position: absolute for the icon, position: relative for the cell with a padding (worked, but not with narrow windows. First image without padding, second image with padding);

[image]
[image]

- position: relative for the icon with right: 100px;

[image]

I'm not sure what else I can try. It's a tricky problem, and I've discussed this with our web designer, but due to technical reasons he can't look at the code himself. My goal is essentially that the space between the text and the icon should stay relatively short, with the icons vertically aligned, and the space on the right shrunk if the window needs to reduce the width of the table.

```css
/* ==========================================================================
 # WIZARD
 ========================================================================== */


/**
 * 1. c-wizard: components for wizards, e.g. "Phase Mass Replace".
 *
 */


/* BEM Blocks
 ========================================================================== */

.c-desktop {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
}

.c-desktop-association {}


/* BEM Elements & modifiers
 ========================================================================== */

.c-desktop .c-table-display__header {
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #a6a2a3;
  background-color: #f3f7fc;
  color: #263340;
  background-image: none;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-weight: normal;
  overflow: hidden;
  word-break: normal;
}

.c-desktop .c-desktop-association__association-item-cell {
  border-color: inherit;
  text-align: left;
  vertical-align: top;
  overflow: hidden;
  word-break: normal;
}

.c-desktop-association {
  border-top: 3px solid #a6a2a3;
}

.c-desktop-association tr:last-child {
  border-bottom: 2px solid #a6a2a3;
}


/*Hoogte instellen via "line-height"*/

.c-desktop .c-desktop-association:after {
  content: "-";
  visibility: hidden;
  display: table-row-group;
  line-height: 0.25;
}

.c-desktop-association__association-item {
  background-color: #f3f7fc;
  color: #263340;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: normal;
  height: 20px;
  text-align: left;
}

td.c-desktop-association__association-item-cell {
  font-variant: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 11px;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 4px 4px 4px 4px;
  vertical-align: top;
  border-top: 1px solid #a6a2a3;
  color: #263340;
  vertical-align: middle;
  overflow: hidden;
  word-break: normal;
}

td.c-desktop-association__association-type,
td.c-desktop-association__remove-association {
  font-variant: normal;
  font-size: 11px;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 4px;
  height: 100%;
  border: 0px;
  color: #263340;
}

.c-desktop .c-desktop-association__association-item-cell--latest {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.c-desktop-association__association-item-related-icon {
  float: right;
  padding-right: 100px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.u-width-full {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<table class="c-desktop c-table-display u-width-full" id="desktopAssociationTable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="c-table-display__header">Type</th>
      <th class="c-table-display__header">Level</th>
      <th class="c-table-display__header">Active Build</th>
      <th class="c-table-display__header">Latest</th>
      <th class="c-table-display__header">Latest Success</th>
      <th class="c-table-display__header">Next</th>
      <th class="c-table-display__header">Action</th>
      <th class="c-table-display__header">Message</th>
      <th class="c-table-display__header"></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody class="dojoDndItem c-desktop-association" id="1" dnddata="277">
    <tr class="c-desktop-association__association-item c-desktop-association__association-item--odd">
      <td class="dndSubrow c-desktop-association__association-item-cell c-desktop-association__association-type">
        <b>Level: </b> COMMON / H_1-0
      </td>
      <td class="dndSubrow c-desktop-association__association-item-cell">

        CONTBUILD
      </td>
      <td class="dndSubrow c-desktop-association__association-item-cell">
        228
      </td>
      <td class="dndSubrow c-desktop-association__association-item-cell c-desktop-association__association-item-cell--latest">
        <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/n7Ycz.jpg?s=16&g=1" title="Success">
        <a href="/alm/levelRequestDetails.action?levelRequestOid=1268">1268</a>&nbsp;[8/21/20, 1:04 PM] &nbsp;
        <a href="/alm/levelRequestOverviewDisplay.action?searchView.projectName=COMMON&amp;searchView.projectStreamBuildPrefix=1-0&amp;searchView.projectStreamBuildSuffix=&amp;searchView.levelName=CONTBUILD&amp;searchView.showHiddenPackages=-1&amp;searchView.showHiddenProjectStreams=-1"><img class="c-desktop-association__association-item-related-icon" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/n7Ycz.jpg?s=16&g=1" title=""></a>
      </td>
      <td class="dndSubrow c-desktop-association__association-item-cell">
        <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/n7Ycz.jpg?s=16&g=1" title="Success">
        <a href="/alm/levelRequestDetails.action?levelRequestOid=1268">1268</a>&nbsp;[8/21/20, 1:04 PM]

      </td>
      <td class="dndSubrow c-desktop-association__association-item-cell">
        9/24/19, 2:30 PM
      </td>
      <td class="dndSubrow c-desktop-association__association-item-cell">
        <a href="displayLevelRequestCreate.action?createMode=request&amp;projectStreamOid=2&amp;levelOid=4&amp;packageOid=" class="c-table-display__action-icon"><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/n7Ycz.jpg?s=16&g=1" title="Request"></a>
      </td>
      <td class="dndSubrow c-desktop-association__association-item-cell">

      </td>
      <td class="dndSubrow c-desktop-association__association-item-cell c-desktop-association__remove-association js-remove-selected-rows-node">
        <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/n7Ycz.jpg?s=16&g=1" title="Remove">
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tbody class="dojoDndItem c-desktop-association" id="1" dnddata="277">
    <tr class="c-desktop-association__association-item c-desktop-association__association-item--odd">
      <td class="dndSubrow c-desktop-association__association-item-cell c-desktop-association__association-type">
        <b>Level: </b> COMMON / H_1-0
      </td>
      <td class="dndSubrow c-desktop-association__association-item-cell">

        CONTBUILD
      </td>
      <td class="dndSubrow c-desktop-association__association-item-cell">
        228
      </td>
      <td class="dndSubrow c-desktop-association__association-item-cell c-desktop-association__association-item-cell--latest">
        <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/n7Ycz.jpg?s=16&g=1" title="Success">
        <a href="/alm/levelRequestDetails.action?levelRequestOid=1268">1268</a>&nbsp;[8/21/20, 1:04 PM] &nbsp;
        <a href="/alm/levelRequestOverviewDisplay.action?searchView.projectName=COMMON&amp;searchView.projectStreamBuildPrefix=1-0&amp;searchView.projectStreamBuildSuffix=&amp;searchView.levelName=CONTBUILD&amp;searchView.showHiddenPackages=-1&amp;searchView.showHiddenProjectStreams=-1"><img class="c-desktop-association__association-item-related-icon" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/n7Ycz.jpg?s=16&g=1" title=""></a>
      </td>
      <td class="dndSubrow c-desktop-association__association-item-cell">
        <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/n7Ycz.jpg?s=16&g=1" title="Success">
        <a href="/alm/levelRequestDetails.action?levelRequestOid=1268">1268</a>&nbsp;[8/21/20, 1:04 PM]

      </td>
      <td class="dndSubrow c-desktop-association__association-item-cell">
        9/24/19, 2:30 PM
      </td>
      <td class="dndSubrow c-desktop-association__association-item-cell">
        <a href="displayLevelRequestCreate.action?createMode=request&amp;projectStreamOid=2&amp;levelOid=4&amp;packageOid=" class="c-table-display__action-icon"><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/n7Ycz.jpg?s=16&g=1" title="Request"></a>
      </td>
      <td class="dndSubrow c-desktop-association__association-item-cell">

      </td>
      <td class="dndSubrow c-desktop-association__association-item-cell c-desktop-association__remove-association js-remove-selected-rows-node">
        <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/n7Ycz.jpg?s=16&g=1" title="Remove">
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: have you tried wrapping the data in that particular column inside `display: flex;` ?

Comment: @CodeCreate Do you have a code snippet I could check?

Comment: `<td style="display: flex">  // Your icons and text goes here </td>`

Comment: @CodeCreate I've tried that, and I can't get it to work. I've delegated it to our web designer, and once he has fixed his technical issues, he'll look into it.